# What is meant by $\subset$ minimal?

Tags: set-theory

Consider a $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and the $\bf{unique}$ set  of $\subset$-minimal elements of  $\mathcal{A} \setminus\emptyset.$

What does this mean?

Is there an inutitive explanation why this set is unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "unique" here is very weird. It would be like saying "the *unique* set of divisors of 12". Sure, it's unique, because we defined exactly what its elements are, but it's a weird thing to say.

Here you have a set $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of some $X$, and you are considering the subset $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{A}$ of subsets $Y\subset X$ such that $Y\in \mathcal{A}$, and you can't have $Z\subset Y$ if $Z\in \mathcal{A}$ unless $Z=\emptyset$.

By the way it should be "$\mathcal{A}\setminus \{\emptyset\}$" and not "$\mathcal{A}\setminus \emptyset$", which is just $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: So therefore you exlude the empty set to ensure kind of uniqueness. Thank you very much.

Comment: No, you exclude the empty set because otherwise the only minimal set is precisely $\emptyset$ and that's not really interesting. It has nothing to do with uniqueness, which as I tried to explain is completely irrelevant here and is just useless wording.

Comment: oh I see. I do not understand why the following should hold then. Think of a partition $P$ as this minimal set.  If $A,B \in P$ are not disjoint, then $A\cap B \in \mathcal{A}$ and $A,B$ could not be$\subset$-minimal? Why is that?